# File time stamp and time(NULL) returning incorrect time during service boot

Tags: boot, services

I'm having a `service` enabled during Ubuntu 20.04 LTS boot.

However, when the service starts up the time is wrong from `time(NULL)` API. Also files created when service starts has wrong timestamp.

I've tried `Requires=` and `After=` on `time-sync.target` with no luck.

```
[Unit]
Description=xyz
Requires=time-sync.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/s_xyz
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Use `time()` instead, to obtain seconds. If you pass an argument (`time(NULL)` it's used a a pointer to a memory location to store results.

Comment: I am referring to the C API time so passing NULL should be valid AFAIK.